# Why does this if else statement not work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to know why my if else statement is not with the two inputs I added and I would like to know how to fix it

```
x = input('Please enter number')
y = input('Please enter another number')
if x + y > 5:
  print ('greater than')
elif x + y < 5:
  print ('less than')
elif x + y == 5:
  print ('equal to')
```

Comment: Wrap input() inside int() like so 'int(input())'

Comment: In Python, `input` take the data as *string*

Comment: The input method returns a string. Adding `x` and `y` together will concatenate two strings.

Comment: Hint: `'2' + '3' == '23'`

Comment: Next time you ask a question please add the error message you get. Here it should have been `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`. Even better: read the error message and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string. You want to convert to int with `int(input(...))`. Altogether we get:

```
x = int(input('Please enter number'))
y = int(input('Please enter another number'))
if x + y > 5:
  print ('greater than')
elif x + y < 5:
  print ('less than')
elif x + y == 5:
  print ('equal to')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because python is taking the input from the user as a string not an integer, so it doesn't work because you can't perform mathematical operations on strings

The Code:

```
x = int(input('Please enter number'))
y = int(input('Please enter another number'))
if x + y > 5:
  print ('greater than')
elif x + y < 5:
  print ('less than')
elif x + y == 5:
  print ('equal to')
```